# Python .sort() not working as expected

Tags: python, list, sorting

Tackling a few puzzle problems on a quiet Saturday night (wooohoo... not) and am struggling with sort(). The results aren't quite what I expect. The program iterates through every combination from 100 - 999 and checks if the product is a palindome. If it is, append to the list. I need the list sorted :D Here's my program:

```
list = [] #list of numbers

for x in xrange(100,1000): #loops for first value of combination
  for y in xrange(x,1000): #and 2nd value
    mult = x*y
    reversed = str(mult)[::-1] #reverses the number
    if (reversed == str(mult)):
      list.append(reversed)

list.sort()
print list[:10]
```

which nets:

```
['101101', '10201', '102201', '102201', '105501', '105501', '106601', '108801',
'108801', '110011']
```

Clearly index 0 is larger then 1. Any idea what's going on? I have a feeling it's got something to do with trailing/leading zeroes, but I had a quick look and I can't see the problem.

Bonus points if you know where the puzzle comes from :P

Comment: It's from Project Euler, I think.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are sorting strings, not numbers. `'101101' < '10201'` because `'1' < '2'`. Change `list.append(reversed)` to `list.append(int(reversed))` and it will work (or use a different sorting function).

Comment: Oh man... just when I thought I was graduating from noob, to rookie ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Sort is doing its job. If you intended to store integers in the list, take Lukáš advice. You can also tell sort how to sort, for example by making ints:

```
list.sort(key=int)
```

the key parameter takes a function that calculates an item to take the list object's place in all comparisons. An integer will compare numerically as you expect.

(By the way, `list` is a really bad variable name, as you override the builtin list() type!)

Answer (score 2):

Your list contains strings so it is sorting them alphabetically - try converting the list to integers and then do the sort.

Answer (score 1):

You're sorting strings, not numbers. Strings compare left-to-right.

Answer (score 1):

No need to convert to int.  mult already is an int and as you have checked it is a palindrome it will look the same as reversed,  so just:

```
list.append(mult)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your numbers stored as strings, so python is sorting them accordingly.  So: '101x' comes before '102x' (the same way that 'abcd' will come before 'az').

Answer (score 0):

No, it is sorting properly, just that it is sorting **lexographically** and you want **numeric** sorting... so remove the "str()"

Comment: On a seperate topic, your program could e optimized. Hint : **generate** the numbers..

Comment: Yeah I know, and I might compile them later, but it's quick enough for the task at hand.

Answer (score 0):

The comparator operator is treating your input as strings instead of integers. In string comparsion 2 as the 3rd letter is lexically greater than 1.

`reversed = str(mult)[::-1]`